# Python lxml change xml object child text attribute

Tags: python, lxml

I have an `xml` that I parsed with objectify from an API output and i refer to it as "result" variable. Now I want o keep the object, but only change the text file and give it back to the API to update the element.

```
<field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="multi_text_area">
  <id>1754</id>
  <name>Devices under maintenance</name>
  <read_only>false</read_only>
  <text_area>
    <text>defwhanld12x</text>
  </text_area>
</field>
```

When I try to change the text I get like this, I get an error:

```
result.text_area.text = 'This is a test'
```

> TypeError: attribute 'text' of 'ObjectifiedElement' objects is not
>   writable

I also tried to strip the element and recreate it as the `lxml` documentation says that you can not change an object.

```
etree.strip_elements(result, 'text')
etree.SubElement(result.text_area, 'text').text = 'This is just a test'
```

But  get a similar error:

> TypeError: attribute 'text' of 'StringElement' objects is not writable

Answer (score 2):

This is because your element is named `text`. `text` is also used by `lxml.objectify` to store inner text of an element, and that's how the conflict happened. When you do `result.text_area.text`, it is interpreted as trying to access the inner text of `text_area`, instead of accessing child element named `text`. You can avoid this conflict by accessing the `text` element as follow :

```
result.text_area['text'] = 'This is a test'
```

**UPDATE :**

The above turned out to be replacing the entire `<text>` element with the new text, which end up as an element in the form you mentioned in the comment below :

```
<text xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" 
      py:pytype="str">This is a test</text>
```

The correct way to update inner text of `text` element would be using `_setText()`, as mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151303/2998271) :

```
result.text_area['text']._setText('This is a test')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! But my response looks like `<field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="multi_text_area">
  <id>1754</id>
  <name>Devices under maintenance</name>
  <read_only>false</read_only>
  <text_area>
    <text xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" py:pytype="str">This is a test</text>
  </text_area>
</field>` I tried to strip the it away with `etree.cleanup_namespaces(field.text_area['text'])`
 but that did not work.