# How to create an objectified element with text with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.objectify

I'd like to **create** an element tree (not parsing!) with `lxml.objectify` that might look like this:

```xml
<root>
  <child>Hello World</child>
</root>
```

My first attempt was to write code like this:

```py
import lxml.objectify as o
from lxml.etree import tounicode
r = o.Element("root")
c = o.Element("child", text="Hello World")
r.append(c)
print(tounicode(r, pretty_print=True)
```

But that produces:

```xml
<root xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" py:pytype="TREE">
  <child text="Hello World" data="Test" py:pytype="TREE"/>
</root>
```

As suggested in other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151303), the `<child>` has no method `_setText`.

Apparently, `lxml.objectifiy` does not allow to create an element with text or change the text content. So, did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc](https://lxml.de/objectify.html#creating-objectify-trees) and the answer you linked. You should use `SubElement`:

```
r = o.E.root()    # same as o.Element("root")
c = o.SubElement(r, "child")
c._setText("Hello World")
print(tounicode(r, pretty_print=True))

c._setText("Changed it!")
print(tounicode(r, pretty_print=True))
```

Output:

```
<root xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <child>Hello World</child>
</root>

<root xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <child>Changed it!</child>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for point that out this very important detail. However, IMHO, this is only slightly inconsistent: `objectify` only allows setting/changing of the text when the element is created via `SubElement`.

Comment: That's correct. Objectify doesn't support adding text to root element afaik. Using Subelement is an option, another one would be to use [lxml.etree](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html)